# Create a new phonegap project

Tags: cordova, command-line

i try to create phonegap project with command-line tools but i get error.

this is my command:

```
E:\Android\sdks\android\cordova-android\bin\create.bat E:\Android\sdks\android\Projects com.example.project_name ProjectName
```

and this is error:

```
C:\Users\Amin7x>E:\Android\sdks\android\cordova-android\bin\create.bat E:\Androi
d\sdks\android\Projects com.example.project_name ProjectName

E:\Android\sdks\android\cordova-android\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Project already exists! Delete and recreate
```

i'm sure project does not exist.

Comment: path issue correct your android sdk path

Comment: @Sport i append "tools" and "platform-tools" in PATH but i get same error

Comment: You are using a *much* older command line there. You should be using the cordova CLI instead. Please try with that.

Comment: @RaymondCamden I try cordova CLI but i get new error [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi14lqq64ot6n69/error.txt)

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @RaymondCamden sorry i edit my commment here is https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi14lqq64ot6n69/error.txt

Comment: Apart from using an older version of PhoneGap, the problem I believe you are having here is that you probably have the folder `E:\Android\sdks\android\Projects` existing already.  Either delete that folder or choose a new uncreated folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your error mentioned in the comment (https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi14lqq64ot6n69/error.txt) is that you want to create a project in `C:\Program Files\` and you probably don't run the CMD with admin rights.

Solutions:

1. (Recommended): Use another path like directly in `C:\` or in your user directory `C:\Users\<user>\`
2. Run the CMD as administrator